# USB connector to Ethernet (and then a router)

Tags: usb, ethernet

ok, i haven't really found an answer anywhere, but is it possible to have a usb cable transmit data through an Ethernet cable and by extension a router, basically what i would like to to is to have high capacity USB drives (flash, HDD, SSD, ect.) and not have any special components a

basicly, if you get my question, here are the tools i have at my disposal:
female USB connector (look i found a use for a mac)
Ethernet cable
possibly a USB phone charger for the 5v DC
basic electrical stuff

(note there is no money in the tools list)

thanks, a solution would help a LOT.

Answer (score 2):

No. The signaling for USB and Ethernet are completely different at both physical and logical levels. Under no circumstances should you attempt to connect a USB cable to an Ethernet port. Consider using a Linux device with [gadget support](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/gadget/index.html) to access mass storage being shared via [NBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device) instead.

Comment: Or buy a USB/Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @user20574: A USB NIC won't give you the ability to use remote USB drives if the OS doesn't already have a NBD client.

Answer (score 1):

USB and Ethernet are very different beasts. Theoretically, you could use an Ethernet cable to transmit USB data, but it wouldn't be Ethernet communications and hub, routers, and network switches wouldn't recognize it (assuming they or the USB device aren't fried by it).

There are purpose built solutions available though.

In software: http://www.usb-over-ethernet.com/

In hardware: http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/USB-PS2/4-Port-USB-over-IP-Network-Hub-Adapter-USB-Ethernet-Device-Server~USB4000IP

These are just examples. I know there are several versions of USB to Ethernet devices available, but the price can get pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

That is a resounding NO. USB and Ethernet can't be spliced in with a simple wire. You either need an adaptor (A Network Access Storage/NAS) or you need a router that supports USB devices, which frankly are a dime a dozen.